# DataGridCheckBoxColumn not Working in read only mode if Styled in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, checkbox

I have a `DatagridCheckBoxColumn` is `ReadOnly="true"` but if i style the CheckBox using the Style

```
     <WPFToolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}"></Style>
                                </WPFToolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

**Where CheckBox Default style is**

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxTemplate}" />
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="0" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOn">
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                To="#FFF28A27" />
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                To="#FFF4D9BE" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundFill"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOff">
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                To="#FFFDDA81" />
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                To="#FFFCE7AF" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxOver"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundFill"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="0" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="DisabledOn">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedOn">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxPress"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="1" />
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedOff">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BoxPress"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 To="0" />
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="IndeterminateOn">

                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="IndeterminateOff">

                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="FocusedOn">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="FocusedVisualElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                          Value="1" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="FocusedOff">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="FocusedVisualElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000"
                                          Value="0" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Background"
                               Width="13"
                               Height="13"
                               Margin="1"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource CheckBoxBackgroundBrush}"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxBorderBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BoxFill"
                               Width="9"
                               Height="9"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource CheckBoxInnerBoxBackgroundBrush}"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxInnerBoxBorderBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundFill"
                               Width="13"
                               Height="13"
                               Margin="1"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource CheckBoxBackgroundFillBrush}"
                               Opacity="0"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Stroke="#FF5577A3"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BoxOver"
                               Width="9"
                               Height="9"
                               Margin="3"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource CheckBoxMouseOverBrush}"
                               Opacity="0"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.886,0.808" EndPoint="0.055,0.119">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCE7AF" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFDDA81" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BoxPress"
                               Width="9"
                               Height="9"
                               Margin="3"
                               Opacity="0"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource CheckBoxPressBorderBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BoxGradient"
                               Width="7"
                               Height="7"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource CheckBoxInnerBoxGradientBrush}"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateIcon"
                               Width="5"
                               Height="2"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"
                               Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Path x:Name="CheckIcon"
                          Width="7"
                          Height="9"
                          Margin="0,3.333,3.833,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Data="M103.78572,598.96112 L105.09846,597.5661 L107.00806,600.16229 C107.00806,600.16229 109.91004,592.74463 109.91004,592.74463 C109.91004,592.74463 111.74678,593.79761 111.74678,593.79761 C111.74678,593.79761 107.88566,602.75848 107.88566,602.75848 L106.60118,602.75848 z"
                          Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusedVisualElement"
                               Opacity="0"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource FocusBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
                               Margin="1"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"
                               RadiusX="0"
                               RadiusY="0"
                               Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </Grid>
            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
        </BulletDecorator>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FocusedOff_BeginStoryboard"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource FocusedOff}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FocusedOn_BeginStoryboard"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource FocusedOn}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsThreeState" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CheckedOff_BeginStoryboard"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOff}" />
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CheckedOn_BeginStoryboard"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOn}" />
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Condition Property="IsThreeState" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource IndeterminateOn}" />
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource IndeterminateOff}" />
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <Setter TargetName="CheckIcon" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CheckedOn_BeginStoryboard2"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOff}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CheckedOn_BeginStoryboard1"
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedOn}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource DisabledOn}" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                   Stroke="#60000000"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                                   StrokeThickness="1" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

then the `CheckBox` is no longer readonly... you can check or uncheck it

I dont know is it a bug or what....

Any help in this regrad would be greatful

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that since you're overwritting the template, the IsReadOnly property isn't getting applied.

Try setting `IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"` in your Control Template